# How to convert this query to the Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, join, orm, peewee

I'm using the (excellent) [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/) for my query needs in Python and I now want to convert the following query:

```
select t1.created, t1.property_id, t1.requesting_user_id, t1.type, t1.response 
from pdr t1
inner join (
    select max(id) as id, property_id, requesting_user_id
    from pdr
    where property_id = 7
    group by requesting_user_id
) as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

So I came up with the following:

```
PDR.select()\
    .join(PDR)\
    .where(PDR.property == 7)\
    .group_by(PDR.requesting_user)
```

but this creates the following sql:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.created, t1.property_id, t1.requesting_user_id, t1.type, t1.comment, t1.responding_user_id, t1.property_details_request_id, t1.response
FROM pdr AS t1 
INNER JOIN pdr AS t1 
ON (t1.property_details_request_id = t1.id) 
WHERE (t1.property_id = 7) 
GROUP BY t1.requesting_user_id
```

I tried a couple other variations, but I'm kinda stuck.

Does anybody know how I can convert my query to Peewee? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (untested, but hopefully helpful):

```
PDRAlias = PDR.alias()
subq = (PDRAlias
        .select(fn.MAX(PDRAlias.id).alias('max_id'), PDRAlias.property, PDRAlias.requesting_user)
        .where(PDRAlias.property == 7)
        .group_by(PDRAlias.requesting_user)
        .alias('subq'))
query = (PDR
         .select()
         .join(subq, on=(subq.c.max_id == PDR.id)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and I now get a message saying `OperationalError: no such column: subq.id`. If you want I can get you a pastebin of the whole traceback. Any idea what might be wrong now?

Comment: Did you include the `.alias('subq')` at the end of the `subq` definition?

Comment: I believe the problem was the JOIN was on the "id" in the subquery, but that column was not selected. Rather, we were joining on the MAX(id), which I've aliased to "max_id" and updated the join predicate. SHould be working now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a million! And thanks for creating Peewee, it is really awesome!